# Hartl RoR Tutorial Chap. 9 Requiring the right user (9.2.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, railstutorial.org

Everything has been going great up until the very last *bundle exec rspec spec* at the end of section 9.2.2. I have already reviewed all of my code and even redid the chapter (three times) already. To no avail. I even undid some of the exercises for they seemed to be causing problems. These are my relevant files. If anybody can possibly please take a look  and see where I went wrong Iwould really appreciate it. I'm really new to Rails and want to learn it. I probably should've started with something perhaps more basic. I will, but I really want to complete this and I'm so close to do that. I have Hartl screencasts and around 50:51 he experiences the same problem and fixes it by simply adding **cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token** to utilities.rb
I haven't been as fortunate. I'm really out of ideas at this point.

### Failures:

```
 1) Authentication authorization as wrong user submitting a PUT request to the Users#update action
     Failure/Error: specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
       Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/> but was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/signin>
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:77:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 10.94 seconds
71 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:77 # Authentication authorization as wrong user submitting a PUT request to the Users#update action

Randomized with seed 47152
```

### sessions_helper.rb

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end


  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end
end
```

### user_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: user.name) }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
  end

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign up') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign up') }
  end

  describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end

      describe "after submission" do
        before { click_button submit }

        it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign up') }
        it { should have_content('error') }
      end
    end

describe "with valid information" do
      before { valid_signup }

      it "should create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end

      describe "after saving the user" do
        before { click_button submit }
        let(:user) { User.find_by_email('user@example.com') }

        it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
        it { should have_link('Sign out') }
      end
    end
  end

  describe "edit" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before do
      sign_in user
      visit edit_user_path(user)
    end
    describe "page" do
      it { should have_selector('h1',    text: "Update your profile") }
      it { should have_selector('title', text: "Edit user") }
      it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
    end

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Save changes" }

      it { should have_content('error') }
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:new_name)  { "New Name" }
      let(:new_email) { "new@example.com" }
      before do
        fill_in "Name",             with: new_name
        fill_in "Email",            with: new_email
        fill_in "Password",         with: user.password
        fill_in "Confirm Password", with: user.password
        click_button "Save changes"
      end


      it { should have_selector('title', text: new_name) }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success') }
      it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
      specify { user.reload.name.should  == new_name }
      specify { user.reload.email.should == new_email }
    end
  end
end
```

### authentication_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign in') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
  end

  describe "signin" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Sign in" }

      it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
      it { should have_error_message }

      describe "after visiting another page" do
        before { click_link "Home" }
        it { should_not have_error_message }
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before do
       fill_in "Email",    with: user.email.upcase
       fill_in "Password", with: user.password
       click_button "Sign in"
      end

      it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
      it { should have_link('Profile', href: user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Settings', href: edit_user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
      it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

      describe "followed by signout" do
        before { click_link "Sign out" }
        it { should have_link('Sign in') }
      end
    end
  end

describe "authorization" do

    describe "for non-signed-in users" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

      describe "in the Users controller" do

        describe "visiting the edit page" do
          before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
          it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
        end

        describe "submitting to the update action" do
          before { put user_path(user) }
          specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) }
        end
      end
    end

    describe "as wrong user" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
      before { sign_in user }

      describe "visiting Users#edit page" do
        before { visit edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
        it { should_not have_selector('title', text: full_title('Edit user')) }
      end

      describe "submitting a PUT request to the Users#update action" do
        before { put user_path(wrong_user) }
        specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

### user_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]


  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

  def signed_in_user
    redirect_to signin_path, notice: "Please sign in." unless signed_in?
  end

  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
  end
end
```

### utilities.rb

```
include ApplicationHelper

def valid_signin(user)
  fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
  fill_in "Password", with: user.password
  click_button "Sign in"
end

def valid_signup
  fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
  fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
  fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
  fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
end

RSpec::Matchers.define :have_error_message do |message|
  match do |page|
    page.should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: message)
  end
end

def sign_in(user)
  visit signin_path
  fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
  fill_in "Password", with: user.password
  click_button "Sign in"
  # Sign in when not using Capybara as well.
  cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the behaviour you are experiencing, it would seem that the `user` is not signed in correctly because the response is taking you to the sign in page as per the `signed_in_user` method.  This means it is being triggered before you get to the `correct_user` method.

Also note that your code doesn't match the tutorial for `authentication_pages_spec.rb` Listing 9.13

Comment: I fixed authentication_pages_spec.rb, but still getting that pesty error.

Comment: I cloned your repo and ran it on my system and wasn't able to get any errors.  Perhaps you could reset the database?  `rake db:drop:all`, delete the `schema.rb` and then `rake db:create:all && rake db:test:prepare`.  Other than that, I'm out of ideas